# ExtJS first tab not activated

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

ExtJS 4.2

If I create TabPanel

```
{
    xtype: 'tabpanel',
    name: 'myTabPanel,
    items: []
}
```

and after dynamically add to it any component

```
this.down('tabpanel[name=myTabPanel]').add({/* ... any component */}).show();
```

first time it's not activated, but next times it's correctly worked

This can be fixes so

```
if (tabPanel.items.items.length == 1) {
     tabPanel.setActiveTab(0);
}
```

**Question**: What tab not activated on first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tabs = this.down('tabpanel[name=myTabPanel]');
var active = tabs.add({});
tabs.setActiveTab(active);
```